# Dump lambda output to csv and have it email as an attachment

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that generates a list of untagged buckets in AWS environment. Currently I send the output to a slack channel directly. Instead I would like to have my lambda dump the output to a csv file and send it as a report. Here is the code for it, let me know if you need any other details.

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import urllib3
import json
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #Printing the S3 buckets with no tags 
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3_re = boto3.resource('s3')
    buckets = []
    print('Printing buckets with no tags..')
    for bucket in s3_re.buckets.all():
        s3_bucket = bucket
        s3_bucket_name = s3_bucket.name
        try:
            response = s3.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket=s3_bucket_name)
        except ClientError:
            buckets.append(bucket)
            print(bucket)
    for bucket in buckets:

        data = {"text": "%s bucket has no tags" % (bucket)}
        r = http.request("POST",                      "https://hooks.slack.com/services/~/~/~",
                         body = json.dumps(data),
                         headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"})
```

Comment: I can't see where your code tries to create a CSV file or tries to email the file. Have you tried using the Python CSV library? You will also need an email service through which you can send the email. This is probably too small a use-case for using Amazon Simple Email Service (SES), so you would probably want to point to your existing corporate email system. An alternative would be for your Lambda function to upload the CSV file to an Amazon S3 bucket, then send a message via Amazon SNS that contains a link to the CSV file in S3.

Comment: You can use AWS SES to send the mail, but on default you can only send to confirmed e-mail adresses. If you want to send to external e-mail addresses you need to make a request to AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html